# dont know how to instantiate an instance when I get TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: tkinter, typeerror

OK so I am writing a program to enter information into a database and keep track of customers and vehicles and installations of products into said vehicles. before I get into my main issue I am just wondering if there is a better way to use classes than how i am doing.
Below Is my main window code.
I have a menu bar class that is common to all windows

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)
        self.title('Wired Installs')
        self.geometry('250x300')
        self.logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Logo1.png'))
        self.full_color = ttk.Label(image=self.logo).grid(row=0, column=0)
  
# Navigation Buttons to open other windows that allow data entry into the database 
        self.lfr_buttons = tk.LabelFrame(self.master, text='Choose', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.lfr_buttons.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.btn_home_new_client = ttk.Button(self.lfr_buttons, text='New Client', command=new_client)
        self.btn_home_add_job = ttk.Button(self.lfr_buttons, text='New Job', command = new_job)
        self.btn_home_manage = ttk.Button(self.lfr_buttons, text='Manage')
        self.btn_home_quote = ttk.Button(self.lfr_buttons, text='Quotation')
        self.btn_home_start = ttk.Button(self.lfr_buttons, text='Start Job')
        self.btn_home_new_client.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(5, 0))
        self.btn_home_add_job.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(5, 0))
        self.btn_home_manage.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(5, 0))
        self.btn_home_quote.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=(5, 0))
        self.btn_home_start.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=(5, 0))
```

the function calls are defined outside of any class

```
def new_client(): 
    window=New_Client()
  
def new_vehicle():
   window_new = Add_Vehicle()

def new_job():
    job_window = Add_Job()
```

so you hit the add vehicle button , which refers to the this class

```
class Add_Vehicle(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)
        self.title("New Vehicle")
        self.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
        self.geometry('300x450')
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):


        self.chk_manual =tk.StringVar()
        self.chk_manual.set(self, "Automatic")



 
        self.lfr_add_vehicle_form = tk.LabelFrame(self, text='Vehicle Details: ')
        self.lfr_add_vehicle_buttons = tk.LabelFrame(self, bd = 0)
 

        self.btn_add_vehicle_save.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.chk_add_vehicle_tranny = tk.Checkbutton(self.lfr_add_vehicle_form, text="Manual", variable=self.chk_manual, onvalue="Manual", offvalue="Automatic")


        self.lbl_add_vehicle_tranny = ttk.Label(self.lfr_add_vehicle_form, text= 'Transmission: ')
tk.E, padx=5, pady=(5,0))
        self.chk_add_vehicle_tranny.grid(       row=4, column=1,sticky = 

    def add_vehicle_cancel_btn(self):
        self.destroy()
    def add_vehicle_save_btn(self):
        print(self.tin_add_vehicle_color.get())
        print(self.chk_manual.get())
```

This is where I am having problems using this get command with the chk_manual variable I thought when I called this window to open I instantiate it. But I get a type error.

How could I improve my code but mostly how do I fix the error so I can use checkbuttons

Comment: Please include the actual error in your question. And please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. There's a lot of code that is unnecessary in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This doesn't throw the error you're asking about, but it's wrong: `self.year = tk.StringVar`. It needs to be `tk.StringVar()`.

Comment: Yes, thank you it was just the missing parenthesis